# Prolog append variable to list

Tags: list, prolog, append

I want to append to a list a variable, N, that's bound to a number.

```
N = 1.

append([N], [2,3,4], Z).

Z = [N,2,3,4]. //Wrong output!
```

I want to get `Z = [1,2,3,4]`

How do I append the number part of a variable, not the actual variable itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid Prolog doesn't have variable assignment like you're used to, just variable binding. So the "statements"

```
N = 1.
append([N], [2,3,4], Z).
```

actually constitute two *completely unrelated queries*. Fortunately, the effect you desire can be achieved by combining your queries:

```
N = 1, append([N], [2,3,4], Z).
```

If you truly need a global variable, you can always use a fact or `asserta/1` to define one dynamically.

Also note: in the future, you'll probably want to make sure you use `is` instead of `=` when dealing with numbers.

Comment: The Devil's in the detail. "." vs "," made all the difference.

Comment: @daniel-lyons: using `is` slower than `=`, since the right-hand side is evaluated, even if it is just a simple number. Obviously, this may depend on the particular Prolog system, and the effect is miniscule, but for raw speed, use unification.

Comment: @twinterer My remark about `is` has to do with the fact that beginners who type `N = 1 + Y` usually want addition to occur. :)

Answer (score 2):

Which Prolog are you using? All Prologs I am aware of, will produce an answer for `N = 1` first. This should make it clear, that Prolog has first answered  the query `N = 1` with `N = 1`, which might look a little odd at first. E.g., here is GNU:

```
| ?- N = 1.

N = 1

yes
| ?- 
append([N], [2,3,4], Z).

Z = [N,2,3,4]

yes
```